# Why does asObject allow use of SimpleLongProperty with setCellValueProperty?

Tags: javafx-8

I am using setCellValueFactory to configure my TableView column using a lambda expression.  The underlying property is a SimpleLongProperty.  I have found that the lambda expression

```
ageColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().ageProperty());
```

does not work if ageProperty is a SimpleLongProperty.

I have found the solution to this problem is to add the asObject method as follows:

```
ageColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().ageProperty().asObject());
```

It is not clear to me why adding the asObject method causes the lambda to return the right type of an ObservableValue.  I understand it has something to do with the fact that SimpleLongProperty implements ObservableValue(Number)rather than ObservableValue(Long) but I can't see why this matters.  In any case, how does asObject() fix this problem?

Comment: How is ageColumn declared?

Comment: It is declared as 

@FXML private TableColumn<Configuration, Long> ageCol; 

I know I can fix the problem by declaring it as <Configuration, Number> but I don't want to do that. 

I am trying to understand what asObject() does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is basically just a type matching issue.

`TableColumn<S, T>` defines a method `setCellValueFactory(Callback<CellDataFeatures<S,T>, ObservableValue<T>> factory)`.

Since you have defined the column as a `TableColumn<Configuration, Long>`, its `setCellValueFactory` is expecting a `Callback<CellDataFeatures<Configuration, Long>, ObservableValue<Long>>` as the parameter; i.e. it is expecting something that defines a method

```
public ObservableValue<Long> call(CellDataFeatures<Configuration, Long> cellDataFeatures) ;
```

If you pass this as a lambda expression of the form

```
cellData -> <some expression>
```

then the compiler will infer that `cellData` is a `CellDataFeatures<Configuration, Long>` and will require that the expression evaluates to an `ObservableValue<Long>`.

So `cellData.getValue()` will evaluate to a `Configuration`, and if you define the `age` property in `Configuration` as a `LongProperty`, then of course `cellData.getValue().ageProperty()` evaluates to a `LongProperty`. This causes a type mismatch and the compiler complains. Remember that the compiler is expecting this expression to evaluate to an `ObservableValue<Long>`; as you observed [`LongProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/LongProperty.html) implements `ObservableValue<Number>`, not `ObservableValue<Long>`. Thus your expression evaluates to an `ObservableValue<Number>` instead of the required type of `ObservableValue<Long>`.

Both the fixes you mentioned work: changing the column to a `TableColumn<Configuration, Number>` works because the compiler is then expecting a lambda expression evaluating to an `ObservableValue<Number>` (which it is getting).

Calling `asObject()` on the `LongProperty` works too. As the [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/LongProperty.html#asObject--) state, this method creates an `ObjectProperty<Long>` that is bidirectionally bound to the `LongProperty`. Since [`ObjectProperty<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/ObjectProperty.html) implements `ObservableValue<T>`, `cellData.getValue().ageProperty().asObject()` is an `ObservableValue<Long>` as required.

Comment: What if i use generic type or boolean ? As i'm using a SimpleObject<?> it does work !

Comment: This problem only arises with the primitive value wrappers for numeric types: i.e. `IntegerProperty`, `LongProperty`, `DoubleProperty`. These all implement `Property<Number>` not `Property<Integer>`, etc. The `asObject()` method is just there to fix this particular type issue, it, for example, converts `IntegerProperty` to `Property<Integer>`. This doesn't arise in any other scenario: `BooleanProperty` implements `ObjectProperty<Boolean>` already, and of course the generically typed `ObjectProperty<T>` is already the type you need.

Comment: I think i have to open a new thread because it don't sove it that way !