# How do you use a JavaFX TableView with java records?

Tags: javafx, tableview, java-record

*Records* is a new feature with [Java 16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_16). Defined in [*JEP 395: Records*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395).

Suppose you have a record such as this one.

```
public record Person(String last, String first, int age)
{
    public Person()
    {
        this("", "", 0);
    }
}
```

This is a final class.   It automatically generates the getter methods first(), last(), and age().

Now here is a TableView in JavaFX.

```
/**************************************************
*   Author: Morrison
*   Date:  10 Nov 202021
**************************************************/

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;

public class TV extends Application
{
    public TV()
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void init()
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primary)
    {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();
        root.setCenter(table);

        TableColumn<Person, String> lastColumn = new TableColumn<>("Last");
        lastColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person,
            String>("last"));

        TableColumn<Person, String> firstColumn = new TableColumn<>("First");
        firstColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person,
            String>("first"));

        TableColumn<Person, Integer> ageColumn = new TableColumn<>("Age");
        ageColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person,
            Integer>("age"));

        table.getColumns().add(lastColumn);
        table.getColumns().add(firstColumn);
        table.getColumns().add(ageColumn);
        table.getItems().add(new Person("Smith", "Justin", 41));
        table.getItems().add(new Person("Smith", "Sheila", 42));
        table.getItems().add(new Person("Morrison", "Paul", 58));
        table.getItems().add(new Person("Tyx", "Kylee", 40));
        table.getItems().add(new Person("Lincoln", "Abraham", 200));
        Scene s = new Scene(root, 500, 500);
        primary.setTitle("TableView Demo");
        primary.setScene(s);
        primary.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop()
    {
    }
}
```

The problem lies here.

```
TableColumn<Person, String> lastColumn = new TableColumn<>("Last");
        lastColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person,
            String>("last"));
```

The TableView is expecting methods of name `getFirst`, `getLast`, and `getAge` to do its work.  Is there a workaround other than doing this horrible thing?

```
public record Person(String last, String first, int age)
{
    public Person()
    {
        this("", "", 0);
    }
    public String getLast()
    {
        return last;
    }
    public String getFirst()
    {
        return first;
    }
    public int getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is basic functionality; check any reasonable tutorial on `TableView` written using Java 8 or later. Just implement the `cellValueFactory` for each column.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Solution

Use a lambda cell value factory instead of a [`PropertyValueFactory`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html).

For some explanation of the difference between the two, see:

- [Java: setCellValuefactory; Lambda vs. PropertyValueFactory; advantages/disadvantages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38049734/java-setcellvaluefactory-lambda-vs-propertyvaluefactory-advantages-disadvant)

### Why this works

The issue, as you note, is that record accessors don't follow standard [JavaBean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans) property naming conventions, which is what the `PropertyValueFactory` expects. For example, a record uses `first()` rather than `getFirst()` as an accessor, which makes it incompatible with the `PropertyValueFactory`.

Should you apply a workaround of "doing this horrible thing" of adding additional get methods to the record, just so you can make use of a `PropertyValueFactory` to interface with a `TableView`? -> *Absolutely not*, there is a better way :-)

What is needed to fix it is to define your own custom cell factory instead of using a `PropertyValueFactory`.

This is best done using a lambda (or a custom class for really complicated cell value factories).  Using a lambda cell factory has advantages of type safety and compile-time checks that a `PropertyValueFactory` does not have (see the prior referenced answer for more information).

### Examples for defining lambdas instead of PropertyValueFactories

#### `SimpleStringProperty`

An example usage of a lambda cell factory definition for a record `String` field:

```
TableColumn<Person, String> lastColumn = new TableColumn<>("Last");
lastColumn.setCellValueFactory(
        p -> new SimpleStringProperty(p.getValue().last())
);
```

We can be explicit about the type of that `p` variable, for clarity: a reference to a [`TableColumn.CellDataFeatures`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.CellDataFeatures.html) object.

```java
lastColumn.setCellValueFactory(
        ( TableColumn.CellDataFeatures < Person, String > p ) -> new SimpleStringProperty (p.getValue().last())
);
```

It is necessary to wrap the record field in a property or binding as the cell value factory implementation expects an observable value as input.

#### `ReadOnlyStringWrapper`

You may be able to use a [`ReadOnlyStringWrapper`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.base/javafx/beans/property/ReadOnlyStringWrapper.html) instead of [`SimpleStringProperty`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.base/javafx/beans/property/SimpleStringProperty.html), like this:

```
lastColumn.setCellValueFactory(
        p -> new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(p.getValue().last()).getReadOnlyProperty()
);
```

In a quick test that worked.  For immutable records, it might be a better approach, but I haven't thoroughly tested it to be sure, so, to be safe, I have used simple read-write properties throughout the rest of this example.

### For other types of data

Similarly, for an `int` field:

```
TableColumn<Person, Integer> ageColumn = new TableColumn<>("Age");
ageColumn.setCellValueFactory(
        p -> new SimpleIntegerProperty(p.getValue().age()).asObject()
);
```

The need to put `asObject()` on the end of the lambda is explained here, in case you are curious (but it is just a weird aspect of the usage of java generics by the JavaFX framework, which isn't worth spending a lot of time investigating, just add the `asObject()` call and move on IMO):

- [Why does asObject allow use of SimpleLongProperty with setCellValueProperty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27464221/why-does-asobject-allow-use-of-simplelongproperty-with-setcellvalueproperty)

Similarly, if your record contains other objects (or other records), then you can define a cell value factory for `SimpleObjectProperty<MyType>`.

*Note:* This approach for lambda cell factory definition and the patterns defined above also works for standard (non-record) classes.  There is nothing special here for records.  The only thing to be aware of is to take care to use the correct accessor name after the `getValue()` call in the lambda.  For example, use `first()` rather than the standard `getFirst()` call which you would usually define on a class to support the standard Java Bean naming pattern.  The really great thing about this is that, if you define the accessor name wrong, you will get a compiler error and know the exact issue and location before you even attempt to run the code.

### Example Code

Full executable example based on the code in the question.

[image: example]

**Person.java**

```
public record Person(String last, String first, int age) {}
```

**RecordTableViewer.java**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class RecordTableViewer extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();

        TableColumn<Person, String> lastColumn = new TableColumn<>("Last");
        lastColumn.setCellValueFactory(
                p -> new SimpleStringProperty(p.getValue().last())
        );

        TableColumn<Person, String> firstColumn = new TableColumn<>("First");
        firstColumn.setCellValueFactory(
                p -> new SimpleStringProperty(p.getValue().first())
        );

        TableColumn<Person, Integer> ageColumn = new TableColumn<>("Age");
        ageColumn.setCellValueFactory(
                p -> new SimpleIntegerProperty(p.getValue().age()).asObject()
        );

        //noinspection unchecked
        table.getColumns().addAll(lastColumn, firstColumn, ageColumn);

        table.getItems().addAll(
                new Person("Smith", "Justin", 41),
                new Person("Smith", "Sheila", 42),
                new Person("Morrison", "Paul", 58),
                new Person("Tyx", "Kylee", 40),
                new Person("Lincoln", "Abraham", 200)
        );

        stage.setScene(new Scene(table, 200, 200));
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

### Should `PropertyValueFactory` be "fixed" for records?

Record field accessors follow their own access naming convention, `fieldname()`, just like Java Beans do, `getFieldname()`.

Potentially an enhancement request could be raised for `PropertyValueFactory` to change its implementation in the core framework so that it can also recognize the record accessor naming standard.

However, I do not believe that updating `PropertyValueFactory` to recognize record field accessors would be a good idea.

A better solution is not to update `PropertyValueFactory` for record support and to only allow the typesafe custom cell value approach which is outlined in this answer.

I believe this because of the explanation provided by kleopatra in comments:

> a custom valueFactory is definitely the way to go :) Even if it might appear attractive to some to implement an equivalent to PropertyValueFactory - but: that would be a bad idea, looking at the sheer number of questions of type "data not showing in table" due to typos ..

Comment: `cell -> cell.getValue()::first` etcetera if I am not erring. Please add some code, as otherwise your answer would be best given as comment.

Comment: @Joop It'd actually be something like `data -> new SimpleStringProperty(data.getValue().first())`, because it needs to return an `ObservableValue`.

Comment: Edited to add a full example and provide sample lambda definitions for different record field types.

Comment: a custom valueFactory is definitely the way to go :) Even if it might appear attractive to some to implement an equivalent to PropertyValueFactory - but: that would be a bad idea, looking at the sheer number of questions of type "data not showing in table" due to typos ..

Comment: This is pretty cool, thank you for this answer. I love that we can simplify programmatically showing TableView using the new Record class. Though it would be even better if we could just pass a record class into the TableView and it auto-generates the columns, then just add the records via the getItems() method. Perhaps such a class could be written utilizing reflection to extract the relevant details from the Record to autogen the columns ...

Comment: @MichaelSims yes, seems feasible.  If done, hopefully such an approach would avoid the issues with PropertyValueFactory, which causes many issues for beginners using TableView.